# Matrix dimensions must agree error in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, dimensions

I am writing a function which gives the frequency of the `n`th key of a piano. But I want the frequency to decay with time, like in real life. So I multiply my function with `exp(-a * 5)` where `a` is some number from `0` to `1`. But it gives me an error:

> Error using  .*
>   Matrix dimensions must agree.

How can I solve this problem?

```
sr = 16000;
T = 2;  % seconds duration
t = 0:(1/sr):T; 
n = 1;
f = ((2^(1/12))^(n-49))*440;
a = 0:0.01:1;
y = exp(-a*5).*sin(2*pi*f*t);
plot(t, y);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to multiply `exp(-a*5)` with `sin(2*pi*f*t)`, element-by-element. That's only possible if the two vectors have the same size. In your code, `t` is 1x320001, while a is 1x101.

I guess what you want is:

```
sr = 16000;
T = 2; %  seconds duration
t = 0:(1/sr):T; 
n = 1;
f = ((2^(1/12))^(n-49))*440;
a = linspace(0,1,numel(t));
y = exp(-a*5).*sin(2*pi*f*t);
plot(t, y);
```

Note that I changed the definition of `a` to `linspace(0, 1, numel(t))`. [`linspace(a, b, n)`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) creates a vector from a to b, with n elements. It's the easiest way to make sure the two vectors you're multiplying are the same size.

[image]